# Why some of my objects suddenly start to move together?

Tags: objects

In my scene all of a sudden I must have hit a random hot key, because random objects are now parented and when I move an object others move as well.

Comment: perhaps Alt+P would work?

Comment: you have proportional editing on, just press O to disable

Comment: Ooo missed out on those sweet sweet points, Chebhou ;-)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. The issue has the same cause but that doesn't make the question a duplicate. Anyways, I accidentally hit o when trying to press 0 and already was worried "what did I do now" but once I noticed that objects are moving together, I had already forgotten about pressing o.  So thank you very much for bringing this up here.

Answer (score 16):

I had proportional editing accidentally checked.

As [Chebhou](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5113/chebhou) mentioned in the comments, this can be disabled by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>.